# Magento 2: How to add text within container via XML

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, containers

I am attempting to render a single line of text prior to a Link list in the footer. Creating a template file to do this seems to be a waste of resources for this task. As I understood it, I could output text with a `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text` block in the layout.

**XML**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
  <container name="footer.column.about_us" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column about-us" before="-">
    <container name="column.about_us.label" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="label">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="about_us.label">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</item>
          </argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
    </container>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links.about_us">
      <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
      </arguments>
    </block>
  </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

The preceding does not output anything, and I am unsure whether this is unsupported, if I'm just doing it wrong, or if there is another more proper method to accomplish this.

To be clear, what I'm currently seeing is:

```
<div class="column about-us">
  <ul class="footer links">...</ul>
</div>
```

when I want to see:

```
<div class="column about-us">
  <div class="label">About Us</div>
  <ul class="footer links">...</ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use the argument directly without the array.

Instead of

```
    <arguments>
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</item>
      </argument>
    </arguments>
```

You need:

```
    <arguments>
      <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
    </arguments>
```

### Alternative

You can also try with the `<action>` tag:

```
<action method="setText">
      <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
</action>
```

### Adding a div directly

You can also add a div directly in the text with the following:

```
<argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<div class="label">About Us</div>]]></argument>
```

Comment: How would you add an argument inside an existing block e.g. product.info.review block can it be referenced and added with another argument of type string?

Comment: @Devtype totally. You can use `<referenceBlock name="product.info.review">` to do so

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism referencing a block doesn't work for me, on the other hand referencing a container does work. Am I missing something!!

Comment: @Devtype no that should work for both blocks and containers. Feel free to create a new question and describe your problem in details ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141891/m2-referencing-a-container-vs-referencing-a-block

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism :
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" before="product.price.tier">
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>

                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

Comment: I am adding TEXT and its not working. I need to display some static text above the price. please guide

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism  . I posted same question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/157169/29175

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism - `<argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<div class="label">About Us</div>]]></argument>` is not working. How do I add div class in text ?