# Is there a generic block to create a title via layout xml?

Tags: magento2

I want to add a title to a block with nothing more than layout xml, is there a generic class or block that I can use for this?

I've just tried page.title.main's class and template but it is too big and you can't pass a parameter for which html heading tag to use. Is there another? I cannot find it in the framework folder either.

```
    <block class="MyDesiredMAGENTOClass" name="account.navigation.title" template="html/title.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
            <argument name="tag" xsi:type="string">h#</argument>
            ...
            ...
        </arguments>
    </block>
```

Comment: You can create basic text nodes inside of blocks, including html. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123664/magento-2-how-to-add-text-within-container-via-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same layout.xml you can set the page title, here it is an example, in the head you set the title of the page, and in the block setPageTitle you set the title for the page. Hope it helps!

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Title</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!--Your content-->
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I don't want to set the page title.