# Add text within block via xml

Tags: magento-2.1, simple-product, simplexml

I want to add static text above the price. I tried to add as explained in the thread ([Magento 2: How to add text within container via XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/123664/29175)) but it didn't work for me.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" before="product.price.tier">
        <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Mytext</argument>
            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: have you tried `<action>` tag ?

Comment: yes but that also doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

This would add your static text block above the price.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="your.block.name" before="product.info.price">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<div>Content of your block.</div>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```