# Magento 2. Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text is not rendering

Tags: magento2, blocks, text

I'm trying to use the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text` block, in a custom view but the output is not rendering.

This is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="custom.test.block" template="Vulpea_Frontend::test.phtml" />
            <block name="some.custom.text.block" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
                <action method="setText">
                    <argument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="text" xsi:type="string">Some Custom Text</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My debugging so far:

- The layout file is correctly used. The page is accessible in storefront and the other block is rendering just fine.
- The Text block is added to the layout. I can see it in the `$_blocks` property of the `Magento\Framework\View\Layout` class. The text is there as well as a property of the block.
- For some whatever reason the **_toHtml()** method of the my custom text block is never called. It is however called for other text blocks on the page **store.links** for example.

My Questions (no need to answer to all of them):

- Am I wrong in expecting this block to render automatically? Does this block need a template? Should I put this block in a parent block and call it manually?

How should I proceed in fixing or debugging this?

**BTW** the whole module is visible [here](https://github.com/victortodoran/module-frontend/tree/magento.stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `type` to `class`:

```
<block name="some.custom.text.block" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text">
```

I also recommend not using the `action` tag as it has been deprecated, use `arguments instead`:

```
<arguments>
    <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Some Custom Text</argument>
</arguments>
```

See [Magento 2: How to add text within container via XML](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123664/magento-2-how-to-add-text-within-container-via-xml) for some other methods.

Comment: That was quick. I can't believe I missed that. Tank you for the best practice tip as well.